# Delphi XE2 Datasnap Callback

Tags: delphi, object, callback, datasnap

I am trying to make a callback, sending different object types and some extra info for the objects. So I made this class:

```
  TCallBackObject = class
    Sender : string;
    ObjectClass : string;
    Obj : TObject;
    Status : integer;
    ID : integer;
  end;
```

In different situations I create different Objects in the Obj field, but I always get the error message when executing DSServer.BroadcastObject "Internal: Cannot instantiate object ..."

Here is my really simple example: http://www.4shared.com/file/fONlAGM3/DataSnapExample.html

Please see the example and tell me what is wrong...

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, the objects classes are not in the executable.
To be sure, try this dirty check. Create a reference in the client code referring to the used classes.
eg.

```
TForm6 = class(TForm)
  SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
  DSClientCallbackChannelManager1: TDSClientCallbackChannelManager;
  Button1: TButton;
  Label1: TLabel;
  Label2: TLabel;
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure OnExecute(AValue: TObject);
private
  c: TCat; //dummy refernce to the class
  d: TDog;  //dummy refernce to the class
  co: TCAllbackObject; //dummy refernce to the class
public
  { Public declarations }
end;
```

Now it should works.

A cleaner way is to use an empty register class method for each classes. As the following:

```
  TCallBackObject = class
    Sender: string;
    ObjectClass: string;
    Obj: TObject;
    Status: integer;
    ID: integer;
    class procedure Register;
  end;
  ...
  class procedure TCallBackObject.Register;
  begin
    //
  end;

  initialization

    TCallBackObject.Register;

end.
```